# Accessing widget instance from file which isn't main.js?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a `main.js` file in my Firefox add-on which requires a class which is defined in another file and then adds a toolbar item.

```
// lib/main.js

var widgets = require('widgets'),
    disabler = require('./disabler');

var toolbarOptions = {
  id: 'the-id',
  label: 'The Widget',
  contentURL: self.data.url('icon-16.png')
};

// Add the toolbar item to the browser. Because this is a CommonJS environment,
// this reference to the toolbar is locally scoped.
var toolbar = widgets.Widget(toolbarOptions);
```

What I would like to do is to change the `contentURL` of the toolbar from within the `disabler` file. However, I don't have access to the `toolbar` variable in that file.

How can I get access to `toolbar` from `disabler`?

By the way, I'm using version 1.10 of the add-on SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each module runs in its own context. If you want another module to have the variable then you should give that variable to it explicitly. For example, in `main.js`:

```js
var toolbar = widgets.Widget(...);
disabler.setToolbar(toolbar);
```

And in `disabler.js`:

```js
var toolbar = null;
exports.setToolbar = function(tb)
{
  toolbar = tb;
};

...

doSomething(toolbar);
```